# cannot find primary outlet to load Component

Tags: angular, ng-switch, router-outlet

I am using `Angular 4` project and I have used `ngSwitch` to switch multiple layouts based on condition. So, at this time, I am getting error `cannot find primary outlet to load Component`. It is because of `router-outlet` but what is the best way to solve this ?
**Code :**

```
<div [ngSwitch]="isAuthenticated()">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="true">
    <div id="wrapper">
      <navbar></navbar>
      <div class="gray-bg">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        <footer></footer>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="false">
    <div class="blue">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      <footer></footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share code snippet for @component

Comment: So if you move the `<router-outlet>` out of the `ngSwitch` the error goes away?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, yes

Comment: Weird. I'd expect it to work as well. Have you tried if `*ngIf` also causes an error?

Comment: No, I din't try `*ngIf`, let me try it. If `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` is outside then it is working fine.

Comment: how about using a named router outlet ?

Comment: what's your router version ? i didnt get any errors for  "@angular/router": "^4.0.0" with your code !!! i guess this error was there in earlier versions.

Comment: @ParthGhiya, it is `"@angular/router": "4.0.0",`

Comment: @JeetenParmar strange, the code worked for me..!! try removing from node modules, adding @angular/router": "^4.0.0" in package.json & doing npm install again

Comment: @ParthGhiya, is there any another way to use multiple layouts for multiple components ?